# Spring Cassandra ddl-auto

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I'm using Spring with Cassandra and I'm trying to deploy the service to an existing Cassandra DB in production, I've been reading about the ddl-auto and I'm not sure if my code will override the scheme or the data there.

These are my dependencies,

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

and I'm using the following to query the Repository,

```
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.CassandraRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
...
...

@Repository
public interface PostsRepo extends CrudRepository<Posts, String> {
    Optional<Posts> findBypostid(String id);

}
```

I don't have any sql file in my project, and my application.properties file is empty.

My questions are

1. Do I need to define something specifically to stop/disable **automatic schema creation**?
2. Is the **automatic schema creation** option only applicable for embedded DB and there is nothing to worry about here?
3. what about **spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl** or **spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization**? should I set them to **none** and **false**? or not having them simply is enough?

Comment: The answer to my question is [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#cassandra.schema-management.tables)

Answer (score 2):

**Spring Data Cassandra** can create the schema in Cassandra for you (Tables and Types). It is not enabled by default.

- If you work with Spring Boot and the starter `spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra` you can use the flag `spring.data.cassandra.schema-action` in your `application.yaml`

```yaml
spring:
  data:
    cassandra:
      keyspace-name: sample keyspace
      username: token
      password: passwd
      schema-action: create-if-not-exists
      request:
        timeout: 10s
      connection:
        connect-timeout: 10s
        init-query-timeout: 10s
```

- If you work with Spring data cassandra without Spring boot you may inherit from `AbstractCassandraConfiguration` and override the method `getSchemaAction` as described below:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

  @Value("${cassandra.contactpoints}")
  private String contactPoints;

  @Value("${cassandra.port}")
  private int port;

  @Value("${cassandra.keyspace}")
  private String keySpace;

  @Value("${cassandra.basePackages}")
  private String basePackages;

  @Override
  protected String getKeyspaceName() {
    return keySpace;
  }

  @Override
  protected String getContactPoints() {
    return contactPoints;
  }

  @Override
  protected int getPort() {
    return port;
  }

  @Override
  public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
    return SchemaAction.CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS;
  }

  @Override
  public String[] getEntityBasePackages() {
    return new String[] {basePackages};
  }
}
```

Multiple values are allowed for the field as described in [the official Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#cassandra.schema-management.tables) quoted here:

- `SchemaAction.NONE:` No tables or types are created or dropped. This is the default setting.
- `SchemaAction.CREATE:` Create tables, indexes, and user-defined types from entities annotated with @Table and types annotated with @UserDefinedType. Existing tables or types cause an error if you tried to create the type.
- `SchemaAction.CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS:` Like SchemaAction.CREATE but with IF NOT EXISTS applied. Existing tables or types do not cause any errors but may remain stale.
- `SchemaAction.RECREATE:` Drops and recreates existing tables and types that are known to be used. Tables and types that are not configured in the application are not dropped.
- `SchemaAction.RECREATE_DROP_UNUSED:` Drops all tables and types and recreates only known tables and types.

If the feature might be useful for your developments, **it is not recommended to use it and specially in production** here are my rational:

- The way to implement an efficient data model with Cassandra is to design your queries first, and based on them your defined the needed tables. If 2 queries work with the same data it is recommended to create 2 tables with the same data changing the primary key. If you work with Object Mapping, (object=>Table) you may be tempted to reuse the same bean for different queries ..with the same table
- Creating the schema in production will require fine tuning of the DDL requests (overriding the TTL, the compaction strategy, enabling NodeSync, special properties)
- Human errors. If you let you `schema-action` to `RECREATE`...good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In case you use an application.properties file, here's an equivalent:

```
spring.data.cassandra.schema-action=create-if-not-exists
```

P.S. This is just for easy copy-pasting. For more info refer to clunven's detailed answer.